# Having trouble running my first Flash project in FlashDevelop (using Starling)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I'm new to Flash development and I'm trying to work with Starling, but I'm having trouble getting my tutorial project to run. The most difficult part has been finding a good setup guide. The Starling guide is quite outdated. Here's what I've done.

1. Installed FlashDevelop (default settings)
2. Used FlashDevelop's "AppMan" to install "AIR SD + ASC 2.0", ver 14.
3. Created a new "AIR Mobile AS3 App" project.
4. Changed project target to AIR Mobile 14.0
5. Added "Hi-Res-Stats" src and Starling src to project Classpaths
6. Added "-swf-version=25" to the compiler options.
7. Copied out the attached code
8. Added my downloaded AIR 15 SDK to the project properties (because it complained and I couldn't find the AIR 14 SDK)
9. Ran program. Got these errors...

> C:\Users\Noah\Dev Stuff\Flash Dev\DemoHungryHeroASC\src\Main.as:21: Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type Stats to an unrelated type DisplayObject.
>
> C:\Users\Noah\Dev Stuff\Flash Dev\DemoHungryHeroASC\src\Main.as:23: Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type Stage to an unrelated type Stage.

Here's my code. What do you think? Thanks!

Main.as

```
package 
{
   import net.hires.debug.Stats;
   import starling.core.Starling;
   import starling.display.Sprite;
   /**
    * ...
    * @author NSouth
    */
   public class Main extends Sprite 
   {
      private var stats:Stats;
      private var myStarling:Starling;
      
      public function Main():void 
      {
         stats = new Stats();
         this.addChild(stats);
         
         myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
         myStarling.antiAliasing = 1;
         myStarling.start();
      }
   }
}
```

Game.as

```
package 
{
   import starling.display.Sprite;
   import starling.events.Event;
   
   /**
    * ...
    * @author NSouth
    */
   public class Game extends Sprite
   {
      public function Game()
      {
         super();
         this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
      }
      
      private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
      {
         trace("this was initialized");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Main` class must extends `flash.display.Sprite` instead of `starling.display.Sprite`.

[Example](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/startup_code)

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much! Also, do I need the SWF metadata `[SWF(Framerate=...` if I declare these attributes in the project properties?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't work with FlashDevelop so cannot say anything about "project properties". But, SWF metadata tag is universal method (independent from IDE) to set frame rate.